# 14.04 Mouse and Keyboard issues with a fresh install

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse, laptop, focus

I have what I think are two unrelated issues with my laptops keyboard and a USB mouse.

Keyboard:
When I turn on the laptop everything boots up fine. Once I get to the login screen however my laptops keyboard doesn't work. I have been getting around this with a USB Keyboard or the onscreen keyboard. The keyboard only seems to work once I have ran "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade". It doesnt matter whether there actually are updates or upgrades to be done; but afterwards it works just fine.

Mouse:
This one is a little harder to describe. When I change focus from one application to another (e.g. terminal to firefox) sometimes the mouse gets stuck in the previous application and wont move from it. 
So say for example I got stuck in terminal I can highlight text with drag and drop but I cant drag the screen or interact with the menu or anything outside of the terminal body.

This seems to happen only when I have multiple screen up and the only way I can free the mouse is by alt+F4ing the apllication the mouse is stuck in. I am using a sensei raw but I downloaded the drivers from : https://github.com/pjanouch/sensei-raw-ctl . I followed the instructions and everything installed correctly but I am still having the same problem.

Does anybody have any ideas on why my keyboard is acting this way or for my mouse issues? I hope question is not too vague and thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything about the issue you're having with your keyboard, but it seems that lots of information has been posted about something similar to the one you have with your mouse [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/362359).

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME and this bug only happens when I use my wireless mouse. It never occurred when I used my touch pad. I read some of the answers and the main points that may help are:

- Unplugging your wireless mouse and plugging it in again temporarily fixes the issue.
- Disabling synaptics in the xorg.conf file may help. However, I did not try this myself. I got the information from [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/362359/comments/20) answer.
- Killing the process which the mouse is stuck in can also temporarily fix it.

Please read the original answers to this bug before following any of the tips I posted above. I am not sure if they really are going to be of any help.

Comment: Hi Eric, I forgot I even asked this question to be honest. I resolved the issue luckily. The problem had to do with 1) my aux port being damaged and 2) that make and model of laptop. I cant remember all of the specifics but I do remember that I fixed the issue adding i8042.noaux  as an argument within the grub boot loader. This was due to the aux port being broken on my machine. I then tried an install on a copy of my laptop and I found the keyboard and mouse shared an aux port. To fix the problem I needed to add i8042.nomux which stopped the mouse and keyboard from sharing the same aux port.

Comment: Alright. You did not post a comment, so I assumed the issue may remain unsolved. Side Note: My name is not Eric?

Comment: Sorry about that I glanced and saw the editor first when replying.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't actually notice someone had edited my answer, so that's why I didn't understand what you meant.